# How are some manufacturers or retailers able to sell for so much more, while others sell for less?

Tags: ford, parts

I have a 2007 Ford Taurus with 128,000 miles. I need to replace my ignition coil and wires, but I'm seeing some new coils for around $35 and some for around $120 (Both online and in stores). The discrepancy between wire sets is similar.

How are some manufacturers or retailers able to sell for so much more, while others sell for less? I'm looking for a thorough answer that will help better familiarize me with how the industry works.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sure that part 1) is on-topic. Part 2) is better left to your judgment; subjective questions are now a good fit for Stack Exchange

Comment: In what @Zaid is saying ... they are *not* a good fit for Stack Exchange ... at least *this* Stack Exchange. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Paulster2 : Yes, a case of keystroke misidentity

Comment: Edited question per the above comments

Comment: The old saying ["*You get what you pay for*"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+get+what+you+pay+for) has some merit in situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

For Ford, Motorcaft replacement parts are recommended. Don't get them from the dealer, most aftermarket stores sell them.

The difference in price dictates how long they will last. Your original parts lasted 120k the $35 will last 20k, just long enough to get out of the 1 year warranty.

Comment: Do you have any references which shows the aftermarket parts will not last as long as OEM? I've bought *plenty* of cheap aftermarket parts which have outlasted OEM. Price does not always dictate quality or longevity.

Comment: I've been a mechanic for 8 years now, i'm speaking from using these parts on a regular basis. I agree that OEM does not grantee quality but in this specific case my experience with Motorcraft has been positive. I also stay away from bottom of the barrel prices as well.

Comment: My experience confirms @vini_i: during my "starving student" years, I bought a set of new ignition wires for about 1/4 the price of an OEM set. They worked fine for about a week and half, until the temperature dropped, and my car wouldn't start. I got a jump start from a friend, and we noticed that the new wires were arcing all over the place. I borrowed some money and bought some "reputable" wires and everything was fine again.